# ldap_add() -> Object Class Violation

Tags: php, ldap

I’m looking for adding some data values in a LDAP server in PHP. LDAP with php is new for me.
I didn’t found a lot of answer at my problem on internet and what I found didn’t really answer to my problem.

```
Here is my code :
$entry["cn"] = $_POST["name"];
$entry["sn"] = $_POST["name"];
$entry["objectclass"] = "person";

$ans = ldap_add($LDAP_LINK, $dn, $entry);
```

My $LDAP_LINK and $dn variables are correct, because I’ve already done the display module. (So, I’m connected and I have listed all entries I needed). I’m sure of that both variables.
When I launch my code, $ans become false and I’ve this php error: Warning: ldap_add(): Add: Object class violation ...

Thank you by advance for help me.

Answer (score 0):

You only can add allowed attributes.  `objectClass` is an attribute type of abstract object class `top`, so you should add `top` to the list of object classes for your entry:

```
$entry["objectClass"][0] = "top";
$entry["objectClass"][1] = "person";
```

Most LDAP servers will not allow you to just pick a derived structural class like `person`.  Always add all the superclasses explicitly to play it safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you look for a helpful error message, you can(must?) activate the logging of the ldap Server.

I use OpenLDAP on a Ubuntu System. You can find the documentation here, https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openldap-server.html.de#openldap-server-logging. This is my logging configuration of the server (file: logging.ldif):

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcLogLevel
olcLogLevel: stats
```

You can activate it in the OpenLDAP with:

```
ldapmodify -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f logging.ldif
```

Retry your function call and you can see the error in the logfile now, i.e. tail -f /var/log/syslog

```
slapd[20568]: conn=1049 op=2 ADD dn="uid=10002,cn=xyz,ou=person,dc=example,dc=org"
slapd[20568]: Entry (uid=10002,cn=xyz,ou=person,dc=example,dc=org): object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'uidNumber'
slapd[20568]: conn=1049 op=3 UNBIND
```

I hope this will help you :)